# Google Analytics traffic surge from China, not real visitor, Baidu?

Tags: google-analytics, web-crawlers, traffic, botattack, high-traffic

UPDATE2: Seems this all comes from Baidu crawlers, here's some outputcreated by GoAccess analyzing our logs. We've restricted the the following user-agent which seems to be used by them:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143
>   Safari/601.1

```
 Top visitor hosts sorted by hits - [avg. time served]

  2535 13 0.80%   13.18 MiB 123.125.71.42
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-42.crawl.baidu.com
  2526 13 0.80%   13.72 MiB 123.125.71.49
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-49.crawl.baidu.com
  2501 13 0.79%   12.86 MiB 123.125.71.17
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-17.crawl.baidu.com
  2501 13 0.79%   13.29 MiB 123.125.71.41
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-41.crawl.baidu.com
  2485 13 0.79%   13.22 MiB 123.125.71.40
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-30.crawl.baidu.com
  2484 14 0.79%   13.56 MiB 123.125.71.30
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-30.crawl.baidu.com
  2474 13 0.78%   13.01 MiB 123.125.71.18
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-18.crawl.baidu.com
  2464 13 0.78%   12.91 MiB 123.125.71.39
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-39.crawl.baidu.com
  2459 13 0.78%   13.26 MiB 123.125.71.44
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-44.crawl.baidu.com
  2441 14 0.77%   13.05 MiB 123.125.71.43
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-43.crawl.baidu.com
  2439 14 0.77%   12.99 MiB 123.125.71.12
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-12.crawl.baidu.com
  2434 14 0.77%   12.90 MiB 123.125.71.16
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-16.crawl.baidu.com
  2428 13 0.77%   12.81 MiB 123.125.71.45
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-45.crawl.baidu.com
  2427 13 0.77%   12.53 MiB 123.125.71.36
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-36.crawl.baidu.com


 Top visitor hosts sorted by hits - [avg. time served]

  2419 13 0.77%   13.03 MiB 123.125.71.33
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-33.crawl.baidu.com
  2419 13 0.77%   13.15 MiB 123.125.71.48
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-48.crawl.baidu.com
  2409 13 0.76%   12.40 MiB 123.125.71.34
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-34.crawl.baidu.com
  2408 14 0.76%   12.98 MiB 123.125.71.14
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-14.crawl.baidu.com
  2408 13 0.76%   12.76 MiB 123.125.71.47
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-47.crawl.baidu.com
  2402 13 0.76%   13.11 MiB 123.125.71.31
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-31.crawl.baidu.com
  2400 13 0.76%   12.85 MiB 123.125.71.20
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-20.crawl.baidu.com
  2387 13 0.76%   12.50 MiB 123.125.71.46
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-46.crawl.baidu.com
  2355 13 0.75%   12.40 MiB 123.125.71.15
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-15.crawl.baidu.com
  2340 13 0.74%   12.36 MiB 123.125.71.13
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-13.crawl.baidu.com
  2332 14 0.74%   12.12 MiB 123.125.71.38
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-38.crawl.baidu.com
  2320 14 0.74%   12.56 MiB 123.125.71.32
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-32.crawl.baidu.com
  2309 14 0.73%   12.46 MiB 123.125.71.19
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-123-125-71-19.crawl.baidu.com
  2247 13 0.71%   11.54 MiB 220.181.108.120
                              ~T~\ ~T~@ baiduspider-220-181-108-120.crawl.baidu.com
```

UPDATE: could it be coming from Baidu? Why would it then run the Google Analytics code?
[image]

During the last few days there has been a huge surge in Google Analytics reported number of visits from China. Over 99% of these are a single page visit, which is really not how it is on our website.
So obviously we suspect bots and something fishy going on but why would these be reported on Google Analytics? Does it make sense for them to run the GA script if they want to scrape us?[image]

Comment: You can confirm if this is real traffic by looking at your log files. It could be fake, I doubt it, but an important fact to mail down first. If it is real traffic, you can simply block the traffic. I assume that traffic from China is not something you care about. I could be wrong of course. If you want to block the traffic, note some of the IP address and create code to block the whole IP address block(s). Cheers!!

Comment: We're an international website and this bot is accessing our Chinese language pages so a global block isn't the solution. Now trying to figure out if Baidu have decided to change their crawl habits...

Comment: Okay. I gotcha!! There is a lot of abusive traffic from China and is often blocked if blocking is not a concern. Still, I would check your log files if you can so that you know more concretely what you are dealing with. BTW- Blocking bot traffic never translates to blocking users. However, in China, that rule may not always be true. Cheers!!

Comment: Considering Baidu is the biggest search engine in China, I'd see the recommendation to block it not much different than suggesting to block Google Bot access. Our website has hundreds of millions of pages (due to catalogs and multiple languages) so this isn't a lot of crawling. The question and surprise was because the crawlers seemed to have activated the GA code hence mess the GA reporting.

Comment: For some, it depends upon what you care about. In the U.S., Baidu is of no value to us. Being a site with Chinese as a language, of course it is of value to you. Keep in mind, that the original question only asked if it could be Baidu. If it is, then I do not recommend blocking it. However, since there is a TON of abuse coming from China, we tend to be a little sensitive. As far as GA, you are right. I get your question now. It is surprising that Google is reflecting the traffic. This should not even who up. Cheers!!

Comment: Very unusual web traffic originates from China. I can't fathom why anyone would do some of the things I've seen Chinese bots do. Worth noting is that Chinese bots often use the Baidu useragent and switch it with others. Baidu can be identified by running the Linux command `host` on the IP and it should return something like ending in crawl.baidu.com. The other major CH search engine, Sogou can be identified in the same manner. I've found blocking abusive CH traffic difficult as they appear to have access to huge bot nets on residiential lines. They usually use the same or very similar ...

Comment: user agent, which you can block (in nginx) by country and user agent. I can identify traffic from bots in China, but they have too many IPs to make it worthwhile. Also, Baidu spiders should not show up in Google Analytics. I suspect your site has been hit by Chinese bots using a browser rather than script. The only reason I can think that this would be done is to manipulate some metrics, like Alexa, Google or something. China seems to be the main country for faking Alexa Rank.

Answer (score 2):

You can check your hostname to see if there's some other website mistakenly put your GA code on his/her page.

The other possibility is that someone in China copied your page without changing your GA tracking code.

I had encountered both situation before.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Checking GA eliminates both options you've suggested. The hostname used is our domain. Interestingly, choosing "network domain" it can be seen the majority is from "baidu.com" and some more from "unknown.unknown" so I'm starting to suspect that Baidu might have changed their crawling habits.... ?!

Comment: Do you mind telling me your domain so that I can take a look with some tools that I have?

Comment: We're both colnect.com and colnect.cn and it's visiting the last one which is where our Chinese (simplified) pages are served. Let us know please which tools you use. Thanks.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-seo-statsformerly-pa/hbdkkfheckcdppiaiabobmennhijkknn I am afraid you just got some traffic from Baidu search. Did you check your ads account? Any lucy getting more revenue?

Comment: This isn't normal traffic coming from a search engine. All these sessions come from exactly the same area (China is big) and leave after viewing a single page. Confirmed with the server logs it's all from Baidu's own IP addresses.

Comment: @Collector can't believe a spider can be so greedy. Maybe you can try zz.baidu.com

Comment: I've added part of the our log summary analyzing only the user-agent they're using. There are dozens of IPs, each resolving to crawl.baidu.com and making thousands of requests.

Comment: And I wish I could use zz.baidu.com (a webmaster tools equivalent?) but I can't read Chinese

Comment: `The other possibility is that someone in China copied your page without changing your GA tracking code` < - very interesting - not heard of that before, but could def be what I'm seeing